# How to setup Istio Egress Rate Limiter for HTTPS Endpoint?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Asking for some examples on creating Istio Egress Rate Limit for external https endpoint, i.e. https://www.google.com/

Comment: Please check the link which has details https://domagalski-j.medium.com/istio-rate-limits-for-egress-traffic-8697df490f68

Comment: check these two [link 1](https://dev.to/tresmonauten/setup-an-ingress-rate-limiter-with-envoy-and-istio-1i9g) and [link 2](https://learncloudnative.com/blog/2022-09-08-ratelimit-istio) and official [web page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/).